# How to add id as a variable in jquery while appending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, google-chrome-extension

```
for(var i=0;i<va;i++){
            var not=result2.data[i].unique_id;
            var matchname = result2.data[i].description;
            $("#matches").append("<br><p id='"+ not +"'></p><br>");
            $("#not").text("hello");
        }
```

Even after adding id='"+ not +" not showing.
The output is not showing anything. I am pretty sure it is considering id as some name but not as variable. How to make id as variable. I am new to jquery, Please help me out. Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: You may want to learn the very basics of Javascript first, using a tutorial or a course. There's a lot of really good resources out there, many of them free.

Comment: Unless `va` is `1`, you're definitely getting multiple paragraphs. But they all have `id='i'`. Look at the code and consider why that would be...

Comment: Aside from the string concatenation issue, don't use incremental `id` attributes. It's an anti pattern. Instead group common elements by a class and use DOM traversal to retrieve the required ones when a related event occurs

Answer (score 1):

When added in quotes, it is treated as String.

Change it to `id='"+i+"'`

```
for(var i=0;i<va;i++){
  $("#k").append("<br><p id='"+i+"'></p><br>");
  $("#not").text("hello");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(var i=0;i<va;i++){
  $("#k").append("<br><p id='" + i + "'></p><br>");
  $("#not").text("hello");
}
```

Comment: A good answer should point whats the issue and how it can be solved. Do add an explanation every time.

Comment: Did this answer make any sense, other than a copy-paste of mine?

Comment: I think people how search answers can spend some time to see the difference and understand what was the problem, right?

Comment: I don't think so.